# ActionListener - Radio buttons

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, setbackground

I'm trying to get a program working where you press the specific radio button that says a color on it, and it makes the entire page that color. The window opens as a square with 4 different color options in it. I just can't for the life of me get the actionPerformed method working. Here is my code. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class ColorPanel3 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

Color darkBlue = new Color(5,41,186);
Color lightBlue = new Color(35,253,253);
Color darkRed = new Color(158,19,47);
Color lightRed = new Color(255,105,105);


JRadioButton lightRedButton = new JRadioButton("Light Red");
JRadioButton darkBlueButton = new JRadioButton("Dark Blue");
JRadioButton lightBlueButton = new JRadioButton("Light Blue");
JRadioButton darkRedButton = new JRadioButton("Dark Red");

public  ColorPanel3() {
    setName("Color Panel");
    setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.setOpaque(true);

    lightRedButton.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lightRedButton.setBounds(0, 150, 150, 150);
    lightRedButton.setBackground(lightRed);
    panel.add(lightRedButton);


    darkBlueButton.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    darkBlueButton.setBounds(0, 0, 150, 150);
    darkBlueButton.setBackground(darkBlue);
    panel.add(darkBlueButton);


    lightBlueButton.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lightBlueButton.setBounds(150, 0, 150, 150);
    lightBlueButton.setBackground(lightBlue);
    panel.add(lightBlueButton);

    darkRedButton.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    darkRedButton.setBounds(150, 150, 150, 150);
    darkRedButton.setBackground(darkRed);

    panel.add(darkRedButton);

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();   //creates a button group so that only one radio button may be pressed at a time.
    group.add(darkBlueButton);
    group.add(lightBlueButton);
    group.add(darkRedButton);
    group.add(lightRedButton);

    lightRedButton.addActionListener(actionListener);
    darkRedButton.addActionListener(actionListener);
    lightBlueButton.addActionListener(actionListener);
    darkBlueButton.addActionListener(actionListener);

}

ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){


        if(darkBlueButton.isSelected()){
            darkBlueButton.setBackground(darkBlue);
            lightBlueButton.setBackground(darkBlue);
            lightRedButton.setBackground(darkBlue);
            darkRedButton.setBackground(darkBlue);
        }

        if(lightBlueButton.isSelected()){
            darkBlueButton.setBackground(lightBlue);
            lightBlueButton.setBackground(lightBlue);
            lightRedButton.setBackground(lightBlue);
            darkRedButton.setBackground(lightBlue);
        }

        if(darkRedButton.isSelected()){
            darkBlueButton.setBackground(darkRed);
            lightBlueButton.setBackground(darkRed);
            lightRedButton.setBackground(darkRed);
            darkRedButton.setBackground(darkRed);
        }

        if(lightRedButton.isSelected()){
            darkBlueButton.setBackground(lightRed);
            lightBlueButton.setBackground(lightRed);
            lightRedButton.setBackground(lightRed);
            darkRedButton.setBackground(lightRed);
        }
    }
```

And I made a new class file to put the panel in. This worked.

```
public class ColorFrame{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(new ColorPanel3());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("Color Frame");

}

}
    };
```

}

Final edit: the above code is what I ended up with.

Comment: Try adding `System.out.println(1);` in the action performed part to check till where it works fine, then add that information to your question and I will be able to help you. One more thing, are you trying to change the background of the window or the radio button?

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what actually happens?

Comment: Sorry Nabeel, I'm not sure what you mean by the System.out.println(1); part. I tried adding it to the actionPerformed but it changed nothing. I am trying to change the color of the background of the radio boxes. When I click any of the radio boxes, no colors change. So surely, it's something in my actionPerformed method?

Comment: What I want to happen is for all of the background colors of the boxes to change simultaneously. If I click on the dark red radio box, I want the background of all the boxes (the entire window) to change to that color.

Comment: So basically, you want the entire JPanel to change color?

Comment: Yes, but the radio buttons are all large (each take up 1/4 of the JPanel) so I think I have to change each buttons background individually for it all to change color.

Comment: No, just use the `Component` class's [`setBackground`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBackground(java.awt.Color)) method.

Comment: @JacobWiebe adding `System.out.println()` in your code multiple times is a very common debugging method which tells you till where your code is working fine

Comment: @JacobWiebe what I also noticed was that your code tries to change the background of the radio button and not of the JFrame.

Comment: @JacobWiebe use `ColorPanel3.this.setBackground(\*your color*\);` instead of `lightRedButton.setBackground(darkBlue);`

Answer (score 1):

Your action listener should look like this:

```
ColorPanel3.setOpaque(true);
ColourPanel3.this.setBackground(yourcolor);
```

And moreover, if you are not writing this code for a **code obfuscation contest** please use different actionlisteners for all the radio buttons.

Cheers.

**Edit:** You will have to add the panel to a `JFrame`

Comment: `ColorPanel3.setOpaque(false);` With a panel that is not opaque, no background color will be visible. `please use different actionlisteners` It's really a matter of preference and also depends on the application. One can get tired of writing `addActionListener` over and over, especially if the actions of multiple buttons are similar.

Comment: @TNT  The first thing you said was correct that `ColorPanel3.setOpaque(false);` is wrong. In the second part, using different action listeners is a very good idea as it avoids code obfuscation but as you said, it is a matter of preference.

Comment: I edited my main post to show my revised code. I am still having the same issue where the press of any of the buttons does not do anything. :(

Comment: @JacobWiebe wait for some time, let me use an IDE.

Comment: Ok, I ended up getting it to work by placing the ColorPanel3 into a frame. A new concept to me. I will post my updated code above - but it is now working as intended. I did end up changing the background color of each button using if statements.

Comment: @JacobWiebe I assumed that you added the panel to a jframe in other parts of your code which again I assumed existed, because your class has no main.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, get rid of these lines:

```
JRadioButton darkBlueButton = (JRadioButton) e.getSource();
JRadioButton lightBlueButton = (JRadioButton) e.getSource();
JRadioButton darkRedButton = (JRadioButton) e.getSource();
JRadioButton lightRedButton = (JRadioButton) e.getSource();
```

What is happening is that you are creating four `JRadioButton` instances with a reference to the JRadioButton given by `e.getSource()`. If you want the background to change color, then this isn't necessary. I get the feeling that the effect of this isn't what you intended to do, anyway.

When creating your `JRadioButton` objects with the constructor that takes a `String`, you're giving it a label (i.e. Dark Blue), along with an action command, which is the same as the text. You can take advantage of this by using the `getActionCommand` method of the `ActionEvent` class to determine what color the JPanel should be:

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Dark Blue")) {
    ColorPanel3.this.setBackground(darkBlue);
}
```

But in order for any color change to be apparent, you must set the transparency of the top panel:

```
panel.setOpaque(false);
```